# Why is there default expression in my access form record source?

Tags: properties, datasource, ms-access-2007, record

when I open my form as design view, in the property sheet, there is a default expression in the record source?

```
exec psel_people,1,24595,null
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKjHw.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the creator of the form and its properties put it there.

If you can't or won't use it, replace with another record source.